# How are the following inequalities concluded based on this first one?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, absolute-value

$$I-\frac{\epsilon}{3} \leq s(f,T) \leq \underline{I} \leq \overline{I}\leq S(f,T) \leq I+ \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

from this, the following is concluded, but how?
$$1.\ \ \ 0 \leq |I-\underline{I}|\leq \frac{2 \epsilon}{3} $$
$$2.\ \ \ 0 \leq |I-\overline{I}|\leq \frac{2 \epsilon}{3}$$
$$3.\ \ \ 0 \leq |\overline{I}-\underline{I}|\leq \frac{2 \epsilon}{3}$$
$$4.\ \ \ 0 \leq S(f,T)-s(f,T)\leq \frac{2 \epsilon}{3}$$
$$5.\ \ \ 0 \leq |I-s(f,T)|\leq \frac{2 \epsilon}{3}$$
$$6.\ \ \ 0 \leq |I-S(f,T)|\leq \frac{2 \epsilon}{3}$$

The first two I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the two end elements in the inequality chain are $\frac {2\epsilon}3$ apart.  That means te distance between any two elements in the chain are at most $\frac {2\epsilon}3$ apart.

Comment: I'm having trouble with: 3. - 6.

Comment: Could you type out formally at least one of those inequality so I can get the hang of it>?

Comment: Subtract $I$ from everything.  The limits become $\pm \frac \epsilon 3$.  The absolute value signs (which are not needed in $1-3$ guarantee the $\ge 0 $ side.